# NullPointerException when accessing relationship of jpa entity

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6

I am getting a null pointer exception when i try to call a getter for a relationship. it is my understanding that the container will fill this field in with an appropriate list object whilst the entity is still managed.

the schema was pre-existing so this is a bottom up mapping.

This is my 'one' side entity of the onetomany relationship:

```
@Entity
@Table(name=CollectorHeader.TABLE_NAME)
public class CollectorHeader implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COLLECTORHEADERID")
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="collectorHeader", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CollectorDetail> collectorDetails;
    ...
}
```

And here is my 'many' side entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = CollectorDetail.TABLE_NAME)
public class CollectorDetail implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "COLLECTORDETAILID", unique = true)
    long id;
    ...
    @NotNull 
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "COLLECTORHEADERID")
    private CollectorHeader collectorHeader;
    ...
    public CollectorDetail(long id, @NotNull CollectorHeader collectorHeader, 
                           long provenanceLinkPk, @NotNull String provenanceLinkClass) {
        setId(id);
        setCollectorHeader(collectorHeader);
        setProvenanceLinkPk(provenanceLinkPk);
        setProvenanceLinkClass(provenanceLinkClass);
    }
}
```

And this is where i am calling the relationship:

```
public CollectorDetail createCollectorDetail(long collectorHeaderId, long     provenanceLinkPk, @NotNull String provenanceLinkClass) throws SystemException {
    CollectorHeader collectorHeader = em.find(CollectorHeader.class, collectorHeaderId);
    if(collectorHeader == null) {
        String error = "There is no Collector Header with the id: '" + collectorHeaderId + "'";
        log.error(error);
        throw new SystemException(error);
    }
    CollectorDetail collectorDetail =
        new CollectorDetail(NextNumberFactory.getInstance().getNextNumberLong("cocollectordetail")
                , collectorHeader
                , provenanceLinkPk
                , provenanceLinkClass);
    collectorHeader.getCollectorDetails().add(collectorDetail); //NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION
    em.merge(collectorDetail);
    em.merge(collectorHeader);
    return collectorDetail;
}
```

Sql Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE COCOLLECTORHEADER (
    COLLECTORHEADERID   DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    COLLECTEDTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP, -- the date when the information was collected
    PROCESSEDTIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP, -- the date when the information was processed
    FILEFORMAT VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    SEQUENCENUMBER INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE COCOLLECTORDETAIL (
    COLLECTORDETAILID   DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    COLLECTORHEADERID   DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL
        REFERENCES COCOLLECTORHEADER(COLLECTORHEADERID),
    PROVENANCELINKPK        DECIMAL(20,0) NOT NULL,
    PROVENANCELINKCLASS VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: We also need to see the code where you're getting the NPE and the stacktrace. Intuition suggests you're failing to persist the linked entity, and I don't see any cascade settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initialize `collectorDetails` with a valid collection object as:

```
private List<CollectorDetail> collectorDetails = new ArrayList<CollectorDetail>();
```

Also check [Is it good practice to initialize fields inside a JPA entity getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791325/is-it-good-practice-to-initialize-fields-inside-a-jpa-entity-getter)

Comment: thank you, that seemed to solve the problem :). 

NOTE: I also had to change the persistence bean code to:

`em.persist(collectorDetail); em.merge(collectorHeader);` because the field's cascade property was not set to PERSIST or ALL. (i got an exception when it tried to flush).

so i suppose from the latter tip that i should only initialize fields in the constructor or on the field declaration to avoid the container thinking the object is 'dirty' when it isn't.