# Date default initialization in JPA

Tags: mysql, date, jpa, initialization

I am using JPA and I want to initialize a Date field with current time stamp (in case the field is not explicitly set to a particular value) 
I don't want to do this at the DB layer because I am using MySQL, the field is DATETIME, and we use a version prior to [MySQL 5.6.5](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)
Here is a code snippet:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comentariu")
public class Comentariu implements Serializable{
...
    @Column(name = "dataCreare")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataCreare = new Date();
...
    public Date getDataCreare() {
        return dataCreare;
    }

    public void setDataCreare(Date dataCreare) {
        this.dataCreare = dataCreare;
    }
}
```

Initializing this way is encouraged [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7791485/1864614)

Do see any problems with this?
I am concerned because when I set a breakpoint on the initialization statement I noticed that the code was executed several times, probably because of JPA 'engine'

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the technical aspects of eager and lazy initialization which are clearly described in the referred post the choice also depends on your requirements and what information such a timestamp must hold, i.e.

- an entity instance initialization time (use attribute)
- time value related to some external object (use constructor or setter)

From the code snippet I can see that `dataCreare` is initialized during creation of the object. If so why would you need setter anyway? It would be an unnecessary effort to reinitialize the same attribute twice, wouldn't it?